# How does a Qt GUI application runs

Tags: qt5

how does a gui application in qt5 runs, what is the ui pointers role in it. I'm new to qt pls help me,Why we will pass this in the constructor like, Ui->setup(this).Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: the uic parses the xml that Qt Designer generates (from form you create into the designer) and creates C++ code from that xml, and you need to use that code into your window class, there are many ways you can use that code, see the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdesigner/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) and using that ui pointer is one of those ways (actually that is a pointer to an instance of a class from the generated code) as for how *setupUi* actually works you can see into the generated code - short answer is: it creates the form's layouts and widgets as children of *this*.